# How can I avoid putting camel dependency in pojo? : camel-example-spring-boot-rest-jpa :

Tags: apache-camel

camel-example-spring-boot-rest-jpa

I'm looking at Order.java :

```
@Consumed
public void setProcessed() {
}
```

I understand this is required so Camel won't need to re-process an already processed Order. However, how can that be achieved without adding a camel dependency to Order.java pojo?

Reason: In real life we need to achieve the same functionality without adding external dependency to pojo.

Ref: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot-rest-jpa/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/example/spring/boot/rest/jpa/Order.java

---

Edit 1: 
As suggested by claus, created a custom delete processor

```
public class OrderProcessedHandler implements DeleteHandler<Order>{
    @Override
    public void deleteObject(EntityManager arg0, Object arg1, Exchange arg2) {
        ((Order) arg1).setProcessed(true);
    }
}
```

And specified that in the endpoint uri:

```
    // A second route polls the DB for new orders and processes them


from("jpa:sb.app.bo.Order" 
+ "?consumer.namedQuery=new-orders"
+ "&consumer.delay={{example.processOrderPeriod:25s}}"
+ "&consumeDelete=false"
+ "&deleteHandler=sb.app.camel.routes.OrderProcessedHandler")
.routeId("process-order")
.log("Processed order #id ${body.id} with ${body.amount} ");
```

Not able to use the Handler, Error log:

```
2017-10-31 15:45:33.688 ERROR 1429 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route process-order: Route(process-order)[[From[jpa:sb.app.bo.Order?consumer.name... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: jpa://sb.app.bo.Order?consumeDelete=false&consumer.delay=25s&consumer.namedQuery=new-orders&deleteHandler=sb.app.camel.routes.OrderProcessedHandler due to: Could not find a suitable setter for property: deleteHandler as there isn't a setter method with same type: java.lang.String nor type conversion possible: No type converter available to convert from type: java.lang.String to the required type: org.apache.camel.component.jpa.DeleteHandler with value sb.app.camel.routes.OrderProcessedHandler
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1831) ~[camel-core-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.start(SpringCamelContext.java:136) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:174) ~[camel-spring-2.20.0.jar:2.20.0]
```

**Solution** (based on @claus advice):

```
// A second route polls the DB for new orders and processes them
from("jpa:sb.app.bo.Order"  //select * from orders where consumed = false
    + "?consumer.namedQuery=query_new_orders"
    + "&consumer.delay={{example.processOrderPeriod:5s}}"
    + "&consumeDelete=false"
    + "&deleteHandler=#orderProcessedMarker")
    .routeId("process-order")
    .log("Processed order #id ${body.id} with ${body.amount} copies of the «${body.book.description}» book");
```

**DeleteHandler bean:**

```
@Bean(name = "orderProcessedMarker")
public DeleteHandler<Order> createOrderProcessHandler() {
    return new DeleteHandler<Order>() {
        @Override
        public void deleteObject(EntityManager arg0, Object arg1, Exchange arg2) {
            ((Order) arg1).setProcessed(true);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you mean that you want to exclude some specific dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `@Consumed` you can use a custom `deleteHandler` which you can configure on the JPA endpoint.

- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jpa/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/jpa/DeleteHandler.java
- https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-jpa/src/main/docs/jpa-component.adoc

Comment: added OrderDeleteHandler and updated uri (see edit), however deleteHandler not wired. URI format issue?

Comment: Use '#beanName` in the endpoint uri, and make Spring Boot expose the class as a bean via `@Component("beanName")` with the name you choose for beanName.